# How to replace string in powershell which doesn't have spaces before and after it

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

We perform password change activity every 3 months. We have multiple web.config files which has these passwords HardCoded in them.

We need to manually replace passwords in these files everytime we update it.

I tried using replace command of powershell to check if it works.

However the string didn't got replaced as there were no spaces before and after the passwords. The line on which these passwords are written are something like

```
value="blah blah blah" password="Old@password!"
```

The command i tried running is

```
((Get-Content -path C:\web.config) -replace 'Old@password!','New@Password!') | Set-Content -Path C:\web.config
```

What should i do so that i end up with below line in my web.config file

```
value="blah blah blah" password="New@Password!"
```

Comment: why don't you just replace the whole line? that seems simpler ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - I don't get why it didn't work? This works and is equivalent, no? `'Value="blah blah blah" password="Old@password!"' -replace 'Old@password!','New@Password!'`

Comment: i can't reproduce the error here either - are you sure you've got the correct "Old@Password!" for the file that fails to substitute?

Comment: Because it apparently cannot be repeated often enough: **[DO NOT PARSE XML WITH REGEX](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1630171)**. PowerShell comes with a proper XML parser. Use it.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - without seeing the a realistic sample, i cannot tell you why your code failed. however, if the line is just that - a line of text - then it is easy to identify & replace the entire line without requiring regex. simply load with `Get-Content` check for the start-of-line text, and then replace the whole line with your new line.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - uhm, my code didn't fail... other than that, agreed.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - i was responding to this >>> `I don't get why it didn't work?` <<< ///// i apologize for getting things mixed up and confusing both of us. [*blush*]

Comment: Aside from Ansgars hint, keep in mind that the `-replace` operator (not command) is RegEx based. In case the old password contains any character being interpreted as RegEx `^$()[]{}` you have to escape them, either manually or with `-replace [regex]::escape('Old@password!'),'New@Password!'`

Comment: this configuration files not only contains few lines. it has more than 1000 lines most of them starting with value="blah blah blah" so i couldn't replace the whole line. @Lee_Dailey  . I used below command to make it work ((Get-Content -path .\web.config -Raw) -replace [regex]::Escape('Old@password!'),('New@Password!') )| Set-Content -Path .\web.config